# Error "no data remaining for table body, required by "list-table" directive." while autogenerating Sphinx documentation for Flask app

Tags: python, flask, python-sphinx

I have Flask webservice like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/ping')
def ping():
    """Check if service is alive.

    .. :quickref: Ping; Get pong response
    """
    return jsonify({'status': 'pong!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I'm using sphinxcontrib-httpdomain==1.7.0. And I have following sections in my rst docs, [copied from documentation](https://sphinxcontrib-httpdomain.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#directive-qrefflask):

```
Summary
-------

.. qrefflask:: logging_service.main:app

API Details
-----------

.. autoflask:: logging_service.main:app
  :undoc-static:
```

When I run `make html` in my docs folder, I get this error:

```
...PROJECT.../docs/logging_service.rst:2: WARNING: Insufficient data supplied (1 row(s)); no data remaining for table body, required by "list-table" directive.

.. list-table::
    :widths: 20 45 35
    :header-rows: 1

    * - Resource
      - Operation
      - Description
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The error above typically caused by missing data. In this specific case I'd suggest to rewrite the service, for example, in the next way:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/api/ping')
    def ping():
        """Check if service is alive.

        .. :quickref: Ping; Get pong response
        """
        return jsonify({'status': 'pong!'})

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app().run(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        port=8080,
        debug=True
    )
```

And update .rst file accordingly:

```
Summary
-------

.. qrefflask:: logging_service:create_app



API Details
-----------

.. autoflask:: logging_service:create_app
  :undoc-static:
```

The example should work and hope this will help someone to understand the logic of changes.